# Closing a question: "belongs on another site" - can we have ELL as an option?

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons, vote-to-close

When voting to close a question, one possible reason is that the question is off-topic and would belong to another SE site. But the only sites to choose from are either English Language & Usage, or Writing Meta.

This is in sharp contrast to practice where most questions we get that would better belong elsewhere are those about correct English grammar, which if asked at EL&U would get summarily migrated to **English Language Learners**. So EL&U isn't where we should send them either; ELL is the right place.

So, could we get [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) as a clickable option so I don't have to specifically write a comment under "Other reason" (and labouriously copy a link for it) every time I'm voting to close a question that belongs there?

(I think it might also look like a better option to others who choose to click the "this question is off-topic" reason instead, which gives the comment that "asking what to write or help rephrasing a sentence is off-topic because these aren't likely to be useful for anyone else" and that's rather off the nose with these questions.)

---

In reply to Laurel:

These are the two I voted on today:

[Can a prepositional phrase start with an adverb?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/67590/can-a-prepositional-phrase-start-with-an-adverb)

[Did I choose the right tenses for these verbs?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/did-i-choose-the-right-tenses-for-these-verbs)

I remember doing the same at least a handful of times in the past, too, but I'm not finding those questions in my history, so I guess they've probably been deleted since.

Comment: Speaking as a mod of...literally all the sites you mentioned... I'm not opposed, though [migrating questions to ELL](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) is very rare. However, it would be best to get a list of questions which you think should have been migrated to ELL, so that 1) the users of Writing can evaluate if they are actually off topic here and 2) the users of ELL can evaluate whether they would accept those questions.

Comment: @Laurel See above. I think that migrating from Writing is very rare primarily because there's a very short time window for that (I think someone once mentioned there's only an hour or two for it) and Writing doesn't get enough traffic for gathering enough votes so fast.

Comment: Looking at what's deleted, I see [1](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/67397/34330) (too low quality to migrate), [2](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/67242/34330) (similarly not great), [3](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/67106/34330) (reposted on ELL after OP got a comment), [4](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/67046/34330) (low quality), [5](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/66910/34330) (low quality duplicate), [6](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/66902/34330) (simultaneous cross post). That's everything since Sept 1, 2023.

Comment: @Laurel I think my memories are older than that. I was most active between December 2022 and April 2023 and practically inactive from early summer until recently.

Comment: Yep, that's just the most recent stuff. There's not much benefit to me spending the time going further back. It just shows that there's not much in the way of stuff that should have been sent to ELL among deleted questions. Didn't look at the questions that were not deleted, however. I suspect that a number of the questions that I would think would be better suited to ELL/ELU are actually not closed, either because not enough people think they should be or we don't have enough close voters for 5 votes.

Comment: I suspect a lot of people comment "Belongs on ELL" as a snarky dig at the OP's language proficiency rather than really believing it should be migrated.

Comment: @Chenmunka If I had that suspicion, I'd be flagging those comments as "rude and abusive". Wow, that'd be some heaping of arrogance. Loads of people have to write in English in professional context while it's their third or fourth language. Try writing an academic research article in your third language and then let's compare notes. And no, it's impossible to even publish such a thing in, say, Czech, at all, not to mention doing so in an impacted journal where it'd count to your citation index, because they don't exist. Or people who work in multinational technology companies and whatnot.

Comment: Mocking someone who's worked for years to get functional and even fluent in a foreign language because their grasp of it is still not *impeccable* would be a very nasty thing to do. And even if the askers were native (which seems unlikely), mocking someone who's trying to learn for not knowing already is just mean. But fortunately, that isn't what I see. What I see is people asking questions about English grammar at a channel that isn't supposed to be about a specific language, and others telling them in good faith, trying to be helpful, that SE Writing isn't the right place for this, ELL is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please!

I feel that a large part of the questions that get closed for belonging on English.SE should actually go to ELL. We have a lot of questions asked by what seem to be non-native speakers that arise only as a result of limited language skills, and I think the askers would profit more from asking on ELL than on English.SE.